# How to replace a duplicate string with counter appended values in multiple files in linux command line

Tags: regex, awk, sed

How can we modify the existing files by replacing a string `"string"` with counter incremented values as follows.

**Note1:** The first `"string"` is skipped.
**Note2**: Also the "string" will not appear for more than one time in one line.
**Note 3**: foo "string"bar -> foo "string"1bar is correct

File1 (`"string"` occurs once inside the file in any line)

```
some text
"string" here
```

File2 (`"string"` occurs thrice inside the file in any line)

```
some text
"string" here
some more
text "string"
why "string"
```

File3 (`"string"` does not occur inside the file in any line)

```
some text
why here
some more>
text pttn
why pttn
```

File4 (`"string"` occurs once inside the file in any line)

```
some "string"
no here
```

How can I replace the `"string"` with `"string"1` `"string"2`, `"string"3` etc?

**Expected Output:**

File1

```
some text
"string" here
```

File2

```
some text
"string"1 here
some more
text "string"2
why "string"3
```

File3

```
some text
why here
some more
text pttn
why pttn
```

File4

```
some "string"4
no here
```

Comment: can the pattern appear more than once per line?

Comment: @Bishwas Mishra, try to select an answer as correct one to close the thread after getting right answer from people.

Comment: No the pattern will not appear more than one time per line.

Comment: Yes @RavinderSingh13 I am trying out the answers.

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated the question. By `pattern` I only meant a `"string"` that is enclosed in double quotes. Thanks for telling.

Comment: Its okay to replace it however it appears. There is no problem for rest of the string being appended with it like your example.

Comment: Obviously you need to run code on the replacement side of the regex. Need this to increment a counter and to incorporate that into the replacement value. If you have Perl anywhere, this is a one-liner at the command line. It's about as simple as it gets.

Comment: What I meant is `foo "string"bar` -> `foo "string"1bar` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question still isn't clear but this MAY be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk -v str='"string"' '
    BEGIN { lgth = length(str) }
    pos=index($0,str) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,pos+lgth-1) cnt substr($0,pos+lgth)
        cnt++
    }
    1' file{1,2,3,4}
some text
"string" here
some text
"string"1 here
some more
text "string"2
why "string"3
some text
why here
some more
text pttn
why pttn
some "string"4
no here
```

Just add `-i inplace` (with GNU awk) for it to change the input files instead of printing output. The above assumes you need a literal string match and that string doesn't need to be separated from other text by spaces, punctuition or anything else.

Comment: The output I got was not as expected.

Comment: I got the following output (please note there are two words in a line): some text<newline>
"string" here0<newline>
some text<newline>
"string"1 here1<newline>
some more<newline>
text "string"22<newline>
why "string"33<newline>
some text<newline>
why here<newline>
some more><newline>
text pttn<newline>
why pttn<newline>
some "string"44<newline>
no here<newline>

Comment: You were right. The code works. However what is -i and where should I add it?

Comment: I said add `-i inplace`, not just `-i`, and there's 2 other answer on this page already using it so I'm surprised you have to ask: `awk -i inplace ...`

Comment: Thanks this is the only answer that came after the bounty started. Its correct and very resourceful.

Comment: More importantly it's the only answer that does what you actually asked for, all the others might produce the expected output from your sample input but they would produce incorrect output for other input that's still as you described (your sample isn't adequate to fully test your requirements).

Answer (score 2):

untested

```
gawk -i inplace -v p="pattern" '
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == p) {$i = p n; n++}; print}
' File{1,2,3,4}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to save output into Input_file(s) itself following may help you.

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -v val="-1" '/pattern/{val++} {val=val==0?"":val;sub(/pattern/,"&"val)} 1' File1 File2 File3 File4
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -v val="-1" '
/pattern/{
  val++}
{
  val=val==0?"":val;
  sub(/pattern/,"&"val)}
1' File1 File2 File3 File4
```

Comment: If you change the order of your two actions, you can get rid of the ternary operation. I.e `{ sub ...}/pattern/{val++}`. Initially Val is an empty string and you will find pattern again since you just concatenated it with the number.

Comment: You can also just do `/pattern/{ sub(/pattern/,"&"val); val++}1`. It might be a tad faster.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/"string"/!b;x;/./!{s/^/0/;x;ba};:b;s/9(_*)$/_\1/;tb;s/^(_*)$/0\1/;s/$/\n0123456789/;s/(.)(_*)\n.*\1(.).*/\3\2/;y/_/0/;x;G;s/("string")(.*)\n(.*)/\1\3\2/;:a;W /dev/stdout' File? |
sed -i.bak -e '/"string"/!b;R /dev/stdin' -e 'd' File?
```

Create a file of all the amended strings, Update the files, one at time with the amended strings.

The first invocation of sed take each line that contains `"string"` and increments it (except the first) and outputs it to `stdout`.

The second invocation of sed replaces each line that contains `"string"` with the next line from `stdin`. The files are updated inline by way of the `-i.bak` option and this creates a backup of the original file suffixed by `.bak`.

N.B. This assumes only one occurrence of `"string"` on each line.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd give this one a try.

Here is a one liner:

```
awk -v strVar='"string"' -v count=-1 '
   NR>1 { $0 ~ strVar && ++count && gsub(strVar, strVar count) }
1' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

you essentially:

1. initialize a counter, (`-v count=-1`)
2. ignore the first input line (`NR>1`)
3. check if the line matches the string (`$0 ~ strVar`)
4. if it does increase the counter (`&& ++count`)
5. if the increased counter is greater than zero (`++count` will return `0 -> false` for value of zero and `>0 -> true` from then on, so it works as desired as a condition for printing too)

   - start substituting the string with an incrementing postfix (`&& gsub(str, str count)`
6. print the result (`{}1`)

Note that if you don't mind also counting the first line, and/or know that the first line of **file1** does not contain the **"string"** then the solution can be even smaller/simpler:

```
awk -v strVar='"string"' -v count=1 '
   { gsub(strVar, strVar count) && count++ }
1' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

which would mean that for each substitution you increase the counter, and would output:

```
% awk -v strVar='"string"' -v count=1 '{ gsub(strVar, strVar count) && count++ }1' file1 file2 file3 file4

some text
"string"1 here

some text
"string"2 here
some more
text "string"3
why "string"4

some text
why here
some more
text pttn
why pttn

some "string"5
no here
```

Regards

Comment: That would fail given various input and variable values and `$0 ~/str/` does **not** `check if the line matches the string`, it checks if the line matches the regexps `str`, not even if it matches the regexp that is contained in `str`. If you wanted to check for matching the regexp `"string"` then that'd be `$0 ~ str`, not `$0 ~ /str/` but you're still doing a regexp match, not a string match, so naming everything str and "string" is extremely misleading (plus is it's not what the OP is looking for - he wants string comparisons). The `""` in `str""count` is doing absolutely nothing useful btw.

Comment: @EdMorton I took into consideration your comment to modify my solution.. I 1) renamed `str` to `strVar`, 2) changed matching operator to not handle it as a literal, 3) removed useless `""` 4) further simplified the conditions and 5) modified the explanation accordingly. I'm not sure I get your last point about the OP wanting string comparison. If you are refering to the fact that `"string"` might be a subset of another string, then a simple regex modification of `strVar='^"string"| "string" |"string$'` would probably do the trick, wouldn't it? If you have any more feedback please let me know.

Comment: You've got something you're calling a string but not treating it as a string and instead treating it as a regexp - that's what is very misleading. string comparisons in awk are done with `==`, `in`, and `index()`,not with `~` or `gsub()`. If you have something you want treated as a regexp, name it regexp and use regexp operators on it, and if you have something you want treated as string then name it string and use string operators on it. Don't name something string and then use regexp operators on it or vice-versa.